# Oracle java and Android don't handle split() the same way

Tags: java, android

The function below is quite simple. It will take an input string. Then go through the string and split it up into chunks of 4 characters and then also split every 20 characters into separate lines.

The strange thing I have encountered is that this function will handle differently on different platforms. For instance, if I run this on my android phone I get the right result which at a glance seems strange because I would have gotten 5 characters on in the first block. This is what is happening on my computer with oracle java. So I change the first declaration of i to i=1 and this works on my computer but not on my android phone.

Why?

```
public String fixString(String input) {
    int i = 0;
    String result = "";
    for(String s : input.split("")) {
        result += s;
        if(i != 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
            result += " ";
            if(i % 20 == 0) {
                result += "\n";
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Input string:

tfJ8CRxisuQQGY3KRcv3r8QRxXVAmHwjL3FvAwjAwLLbMvtcVrUEBLuCzMYW7JJ6n6kVJwmzP 8Jqyjx4PiFscTuzEeaCcYLeaBT3tV5kr8Z

PC Output:

```
tfJ8C Rxis uQQG Y3KR cv3r 
8QRx XVAm HwjL 3FvA wjAw 
LLbM vtcV rUEB LuCz MYW7 
JJ6n 6kVJ wmzP 8Jqy jx4P 
iFsc TuzE eaCc YLea BT3t 
V5kr 8Z
```

Android output:

```
I/System.out: tfJ8 CRxi suQQ GY3K Rcv3 
I/System.out: r8QR xXVA mHwj L3Fv AwjA 
I/System.out: wLLb Mvtc VrUE BLuC zMYW 
I/System.out: 7JJ6 n6kV Jwmz P8Jq yjx4 
I/System.out: PiFs cTuz EeaC cYLe aBT3 
I/System.out: tV5k r8Z
```

Comment: It is somewhat more likely to be `String.split()`, don't you think, than the rather well-defined *remainder* operator? What is your input string? And outputs in both platforms?

Comment: Sounds reasonable maybe the split function on "" interpret the string as having either a start before the first byte or after. Strange that they separate the functionality like that.

I wonder if there is a platform independent split function.

Comment: What *I* wonder is why you're using `String.split()` at all, in a way which seems to be undefined, when you could just be traversing the characters.

Comment: Well, that's a great question. Even though it's undefined many use it that way and I have also seen it mentioned as a solution on this very site. After I've changed my solution seems much more correct but still strange that the implementations differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed like EJP was right about the split function.
Changed my code to get the char array instead and that worked.

```
public String fixString(String input) {
    int i = 1;
    String result = "";
    for(char s : input.toCharArray()) {
        result += s;
        if(i != 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
            result += " ";
            if(i % 20 == 0) {
                result += "\n";
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```